# Printing data accross sheets in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to Excel VBA and below is what I did so far and the issue I need to solve.

I've got 16 sheets in total of which the 1st sheet is named as **Data** and the rest of the sheets are re-named as R1, R2, R3 up to R15. There are certain data needs to be copied to respective 15 'R' sheets once you click on a button available in **Data** sheet.

Code I have as follows;

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim items As Range, item As Range, sht As Long, col As Long, rw As Long

    Set items = Range("A3:A" & Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row)


    sht = 1
    rw = 15

    For Each item In items

        With Worksheets("R" & sht)
            .Range("B9") = item


                For col = 6 To 36
                    If item.Offset(0, col - 1) <> vbNullString Then
                        .Range("B" & rw) = Cells(1, col)
                        .Range("D" & rw) = item.Offset(0, col - 1)
                        rw = rw + 1
                    End If
                Next col

        End With

        sht = sht + 1
        rw = 15
    Next item
End sub
```

The issue I get is (rather as VBA tells me) is with `With Worksheets("R" & sht)` and it says `Run-time error:'9'` and `Subscript out of range`. My knowledge is limited to solve the issue and your help is much appreciated.

Comment: What it's telling you is that sheet `"R" & sht` doesn't exist.  When you get the error, check the value of `sht`, and if that sheet exists.  Watch out for stray spaces in the actual sheet names.

Comment: @chrisneilsen you're right. `sht` has a value of 16 when the error pops up. But how do I limit the code to not to go to R16 but stop at R15? Thanks

Comment: That would depend on what you want to do with the data on sheet `Data` in excess of 15 rows.

Comment: ok..figured something out! Thanks